# TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable

Tags: python, loops, discord.py

I am newer to asynchronous coding. I am trying to resolve the error: `TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable`. The code I am using is below.

```
async def on_message(message):
    for msg in message.channel.history:
            fetched_message = await message.channel.fetch_message(msg.id)
            reactions = fetched_message.reactions
            users = []
            for reaction in reactions:
                    users = await reaction.users().flatten() 
                    for u in users:
                            print(message.id, reaction, u, message.channel, 1)
```

This code block works, but I want to loop it like above.

```
    fetched_message = await message.channel.fetch_message(1111111)
    reactions = fetched_message.reactions
    users = []
    for reaction in reactions:
            users = await reaction.users().flatten() 
            for u in users:
                    print(message.id, reaction, u, message.channel, 1)
```

EDIT:

This is the loop having an error
`for msg in message.channel.history: TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable`

EDIT EDIT:
This ended up being the solution after troubleshooting

```
    async def on_message(message):
            async for msg in message.channel.history(limit=None):  
                    users = [] 
                    for reaction in msg.reactions:
                        users = await reaction.users().flatten() 
                        for u in users:
```

Comment: There are a lot of loops there. Which one is causing the error?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: I updated the full error, the issue is when I introduce the first two lines. Comparing to the code block below, everything is identical except the first two lines.

Answer (score 1):

The comments from another answer (which has now been removed) suggest that you're using a deprecated version of `discord.py`. You should update to 2.X, as 1.7 is no longer supported as of this month.

Your original error is caused by you not calling the method. `channel.history` is just a method reference, you have to actually *call* it.

In Discord.py 2.0, all async iterators (including `Messageable.history()`) were changed. `.flatten()` is no more.

Migration guide (explaining how to convert every old method into the new version): https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#moving-away-from-custom-asynciterator

Docs for `history` (with two examples): https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.history

**Note: the same thing goes for your `reaction.users().flatten()` a few lines later!!**